# Фильтрация file_get_contents

Tags: ulogin, php

Всем привет, решил поставить Ulogin (виджет авторизации через социальные сети). Вот, у меня вопрос стоит ли как-то фильтровать что там приходит через file_get_contents?

```
$s = file_get_contents('http://ulogin.ru/token.php?token=' . $_POST['token'] . '&host=' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$user = json_decode($s, true);
```

Comment: всё что приходит не от вас всегда нужно фильтровать, даже из банков и правительственных организаций (точнее *особенно* из банков и пр.).

Comment: А собствено что там фильтровать:
$user['network'] - соц. сеть, через которую авторизовался пользователь
$user['identity'] - уникальная строка определяющая конкретного пользователя соц. сети
$user['first_name'] - имя пользователя
$user['last_name'] - фамилия пользователя
Тут приходит только идентификация, а все остальное вы уже у себя делаете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё приходит с ulogin, но лучше фильтровать всё!